# Find and print final redirect url using Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

Is there any way that I can use JavaScript to get the final redirect URL of a domain?

Let's say, I have a simple HTML webpage at the URL `http://dummy.com/script.html` containing the potential script which checks for the redirection of a user submitted URL. That is, if a user has submitted the URL `http://example.com` and it automatically redirects to `http://example.org/abc`.

Can we write a script that follows the redirection and prints out all the redirection URLs. Of course, my only interest is to get the final redirection URL and store it in a variable so that I can use further down.

Any ideas??

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do that across domain boundaries.

Comment: @spender: It’s likely going to be difficult even within the same domain.

Comment: @spender I've done it using PHP, but the blogger.com only allows HTML and javascript. So, I've been stuck there for a while now.

Comment: So, you'd need to submit the URL in question from Javascript to a CORS enabled web method in PHP.

Comment: Javascript doesn't even allow accessing other domains, let alone watching all the details of the HTTP process.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What problem are you really trying to solve with this? Why do you need the final domain in a variable?

Comment: @Barmar I have a permanent URL which when executed will be redirected to a temporary video link (the video is stored on an external server and domain) which can be used in any video player like JWplaer or VideoJS. As you can imagine, being a temporary link I cannot directly use the video link.

So, what I thought is that every time a user tries to access the video, the javascript should automatically fetch the temporary video link and use it in the video player.

Comment: Sounds like they're specifically trying to prevent you from doing this, that's the point of making the link temporary.